# Background check stage, contact current employer

Tags: new-job, background-check

I accepted a job offer, received a start date, and all the other details of the job. I received an email from a company that does background checks and one of the questions is if they can contact my current employer. I don't start the new job for a couple of months, is it fine to say "No" to contacting my current employer? I just want to make sure everything passes and the new job is 100% secured.

Will it look bad on the background check if I select "No"? I want to keep working at my current job as the new job doesn't start for a few months. I feel like it might look bad if my current employer knew that I'm searching for other opportunities.

Any advice would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: " I want to keep working at my current job ". That's your answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So it won't look bad on the background check?

Comment: Saying No would be a red flag to your new employer and saying yes would be a red flag to your current employer. Just say No and stay in your current job that you like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point, you will have to hand in your notice with your current employer. You should inform the background check people that they can contact your current employer *after* you have handed in your notice.

As for the notice period, it is customary to have a handover as part of your notice period. Why not offer your employer the chance to have someone fully trained and up to speed by handing in your notice early, giving a longer notice period than your contracted minimum?

Comment: Agree with the answer, but be careful with wording. "Yes, after I have given notice" and "No, not now. After I have given notice, I'll send you an e-mail and you're free to contact my current employer." could make quite a difference here.